# Owl Carousel Video Preloading

Tags: html, video, preload, owl-carousel-2

I have a complex custom Owl Carousel here which has 27 slides, within which there are around 25 MP4 videos (approx 2Mb in size each).

The videos are locally stored, HTML5  tags and have preload="auto" in there.

My problem is heavy stuttering due to the sheer size (20Mb in total for the videos) and I'm unsure as to how to sort it.

Does anyone know of any decent preloading solutions, or how I could go about selectively loading/destroying videos within an Owl Carousel item on slide?

Thanks!
Graham

Comment: Take a look at the [preload](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp) attribute. You could set it to "none" and then on slide set the preload attribute of the currently visible video(s) to "auto". I have no experience with Owl Carousel so I don't know how to listen for the "slide" event. Alternatively instead of setting `preload` you could try with putting video tags with empty `src` attributes and then set the `src` on slide.

Comment: I never thought of the latter approach - that's a great idea! Thanks Svetlin :)